My simple SpringBoot app opens a home page when there is none in the code
I've tried to add a html home page for my web app and removed it later. Now when I run my application, It always opens like this:

but there's no frontend code in my app currently.
I've removed all the html, jsp files from the directory and removed the reference from application.properties file. there's no web app directory in my project now. And cleared cache from my browsers. The result is still the same from different browsers (incognito or otherwise). Please help.
P.S. I've also tried restarting my laptop. And tried to use a different html page inside webapp/WEB-INF with configuration added to application.properties.
repo structure

Don't you have a controller mapped to / which returns the string "home"? This might be it. I mean, when you return the string "home" and you access it through the browser, the browser has to show you the returned content somehow. The way it does is by creating the HTML structure needed to render the result. This does not mean that you are the one returning the HTML markups.

@Matheus that was it. Can't believe I didn't check that. Thanks!
